# How to manage local sql server database files?

Tags: sql-server

My system is for development, and I run a local copy of sql server 2005. I want to move all the database files out of program files, and put in a better location on another partition. To do this would you simply detach all the databases in SSMS, move the .mdf and .ldf files with windows explorer, then reattach?

Answer (score 1):

That should work.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224071

Comment: The only *safe* way... without restores

Answer (score 0):

Yes, detach and re-attach them.  If you are going to move the system databases also, that will take some special effort.  Instructions for that can be found on MSDN.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345408(SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you are looking for. I would want to write my answer here but I am too lazy to do that, but I am sending you to my blog post regarding Moving Data File in SQL Server;

http://dbalink.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/how-to-moving-data-files/